# Strange 404 error - trying to avoid with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a fairly simple web site in which I trap any 404 errors and one that's started coming through is trying to access /home/sycamore/public_html/...valid url... instead of /...valid url...

Obviously /home/sycamore/public_html/ is the file path to where the site lives but firstly, how on earth is this request being generated.  I can find nothing in my code that does anything like that and yet it is happening in just one area that;s been recently added.  Any idea what can caused this?

In an attempt to avoid this I've added a rule to the .htaccess file so it now starts

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^/home/sycamore/public_html/(.*)$    /$1 [R,L]
```

However, this doesn't appear to do anything, I'm still getting the 404 reported on /home/sycamore/public_html/...valid url... although there are many other rewrite and redirect rules in .htaccess which work perfectly.

Any ideas as to (1) why the problem might be there in the first place and (2) why my htaccess attempt to 'correct' the url is failing?

I would also add that most of the requests for this URL are coming from search bots; google, yahoo, etc. and there is no mention of /home/... in the sitemap.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the original cause was down to some redirects in the htaccess file which were redirecting to a non-existent page and, I assume, causing it to generate this sort of error.

Still no idea why the attempted fix to rewrite the url didn't work but hopefully mending the htaccess file will have got rid of a lot of the problems (though there are still some unaccounted ones).